# How to check if string exists in database and redo if so

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm creating a paste system sort of and when inserting into the database I need to check if the unique code already exists and if so, generate a new one, my code so far:

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST["snip"]) && !empty($_POST["snip"])) {

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("ezsnip")or die("cannot select DB");



  $snip = $_POST['snip'];
  $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $language = $_POST['language'];
  $userID = '1';
  $length = 4;
  $rand = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

  $snip = mysql_real_escape_string($snip);
  $userIP = mysql_real_escape_string($userIP);
  $rand = mysql_real_escape_string($rand);
  $language = mysql_real_escape_string($language);


$sql="INSERT INTO snips(ID, Snip, Language, UserID, UniqueID, IP)VALUES('', '$snip', '$language', '$userID', '$rand', '$userIP')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
if($result){
//Good to go
} else {
//Error
    }
} else {
 echo 'no';
}
?>
```

And is the way of inserting secure? I'm newer, all info will help.

Comment: You should **definetly not** use mysql_. Instead use mysqli_ or pdo. For full security you should use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: use mysql**i** not mysql, check the content of your data received from `$_POST` e.g. using `filter_var()` and bind the values using prepared statements. Finally, check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: There's no need to escape `$rand` since it's value has nothing to do with the user's input; the same goes for the `$userIP` variable. Also, you can shorten your code by declaring your variables like this: `$snip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['snip']);`

Comment: use a password_hash instead, so that you'll never have to worry about this

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows()` to check if a row exists with given data.

Comment: @Xatenev definetly is a word too strong for this imo because mysql is still safe. Also, I think that for a guy that's new to PHP and maybe programming the most important thing to learn is the logic behind an app, not the functions. The downside of using mysql is that, in, let's say a couple of years, it will be removed; for now it's just deprecated. Stop chasing mysql code just so you post your 'use PDO/ mysqli' comments, it's not helping at all.

Comment: @TraianTatic Its just an advice - so it is a comment :). I would write an answer on his question otherwise. `Also, I think that for a guy that's new to PHP and maybe programming the most important thing to learn is the logic behind an app, not the functions.` -> You don't learn logic by using mysqli/pdo ?

Comment: @Xatenev The idea is he is a bit confused already and he should clear his questions at first and then master the best/ newest/ trendiest ways of achieving his goal.